# BizTalk database lookup functoid - Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am implementing unit tests for BizTalk.

I am able to unit test BizTalk Maps as long as it does not contain external functoids like the `Database Lookup`.

**Is there any way to fake the `Database Lookup` functoid so that I can properly unit tests my BizTalk maps?**

I have tried the proposed solution on http://truenorthit.co.uk/2014/11/17/unit-testing-biztalk-maps-external-functoids/ but without success.

I have also tried to find a way to use `Microsoft Fakes` but I cannot find which component I need to fake.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My first attempt to answer didn't work. This one does.

I only have VS 2010 on my BizTalk VM so this is with Moles but it should work the same with Fakes I hope. It executes the xslt transform directly and overrides the extension objects collection with a detoured (shimmed) one. The Moled assembly here is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Developer Tools\Microsoft.BizTalk.BaseFunctoids.dll".

```
var inputStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetManifestResourceStream("TestProject.TestFile.xml");
XPathDocument xpath = new XPathDocument(inputStream);

var myFunctoids = new Microsoft.BizTalk.BaseFunctoids.Moles.MFunctoidScripts();
myFunctoids.DBLookupInt32StringStringStringString = (a, b, c, d, e) => "1";
myFunctoids.DBValueExtractInt32String = (a, b) => "result";
myFunctoids.DBLookupShutdown = () => "";

XsltArgumentList extensionObjects = new XsltArgumentList();
extensionObjects.AddExtensionObject("http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ScriptNS0", 
                                    myFunctoids.Instance);

var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

var myMap = (Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransformBase)new Map1();
myMap.Transform.Transform(xpath, extensionObjects, outputStream);

outputStream.Position = 0;
Assert.AreEqual("<expected>result</expected>", new StreamReader(outputStream).ReadToEnd());
```